# How to list options in drop down based on some condition in Angular mat-options?

Tags: angular

I have an array of applications. Here I need to list the application names in drop down. But some application names are null. So in drop down I am getting those applications also, as it does not have names just displaying blank option.
Is there any way to avoid those application names listing as option in drop down ?

**My code is as follows:**

**app.component.html**

```
<span style="font-size: 15px">Apps</span>
<mat-select [(value)]="apps.id" [(ngModel)]="apps.id" name="apps.id" style="width:1%">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let app of apps" [value]="app.id">
             {{app.name}}
     </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
getApps(loggedInUser) {           
    this.processAdminServices.getApps(loggedInUser)
         .subscribe(data =>{ 
                let appsData = data["data"];
                this.apps = appsData;
                console.log("APPS LIST ARE AS FOLLOWS:");
                console.dir(this.apps);
          },
          errorCode =>  {
               this.statusCode = errorCode
          });
 }
```

**App array:**

[image]

Here I don't want list the applications as option in drop down which are having name as null.
[image]

How to achieve this? Please provide solution for achieving this.

Thanks & Regards,

Shilpa Kulkarni

Answer (score 2):

Use a condition along with a `ng-container`. Check on truthy values : this means thats if your app has either of these values `['', undefined, null]`, it won't be shown.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let app of apps">
  <mat-option *ngIf="app.name" [value]="app.id">
    {{app.name}}
  </mat-option>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **ng-container**

here's example

```
<mat-select [(value)]="apps.id" [(ngModel)]="apps.id" name="apps.id" style="width :1%">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let app of apps">
        <mat-option *ngIf="app.name != null"  [value]="app.id">
           {{app.name}}
        </mat-option>
  </ng-container>

</mat-select>
```

and in **.ts**

```
apps = [
    { id: 1, name: null },
    { id: 2, name: null },
    { id: 3, name: 'test1'},
    { id: 4, name: 'test2'}

  ]
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to filter the apps when you receive them:

```
let appsData = data["data"];
this.apps = appsData.filter(app => { 
  if(app.id != null) { 
    return app;
  } 
});
```

---

This discards the apps from your component, because it seems to be what you want to do. If it's not the case and you want to keep them you could work with another array:

```
public appsToRender = [];

...

let appsData = data["data"];
this.appsData = appsData;
this.appsToRender = appsData.filter(...)
```

And in your template:

```
*ngFor="let app of appsToRender"
```

---

**Important**: As trichetriche noted, your filter function should return true or false rather than any value or void.

```
return app.id != null;
```

Comment: Given that this is only for displaying (as per the OP requirement), you should not do that. By doing this, you lose any reference to your apps that have an empty name, and you won't be able to find them anymore.

Comment: @trichetriche I hope it's not the reason for which you downvoted because this is a working solution and it's quite easy to work around the 'problem' you define, just build another list for rendering. It's that simple.

Comment: 1) You've read it, 2) it doesn't work if `app.name === ''` 3) it doesn't work if `app.name === undefined` 4) You can write it on one line 5) you forgot an `else` making your filter not returning in this case, thus breaking it. So no, it's not the only reason I downvoted. Now get down of your high horse, and test a solution before posting it.

Comment: Also, just because `it's quite easy to work around the 'problem' [I] define`, doesn't mean it's the best practice. The Angular teams recommand you use the HTML to handle visibility of DOM elements if it's easy to do, in order to avoid overloading the Typescript code, what your function is doing. Finally, if it's "that simple" to do, then maybe you should have though about it yourself.

Comment: 1) N/A 2&3) `it doesn't work if app.name === ''` I discard ids that are null since 'broken' apps have no id. 4) What can I write in 1 line ? 5) I'm unfortunately not the only one doing this, a filter should return a boolean, though I understand why it worked previously so it was not broken in any way in JS due to its flexibility. 6) I did test my solution and it was confirmed by the user to work before you even posted your paragraph. I won't talk about this final childish disrespectful sentence.

Comment: 7) It's a 2 lines solution if you want to keep both arrays, I added it just for you because I'm pretty sure the user wants to discard them. 8) Of course the Angular team do say that, it's the purpose of those directives, though as I said, it's not about visibility but rather discarding unwanted items.

Comment: @Ploppy `as it does not have names just displaying blank option` means you must discard falsy values, not only null values. `.filter(app => app.id !== null)` is a one liner. I won't answer other points you made, it seems like you have answers to everything and I don't have time for that. I just answered those two so that you actually learn something useful (no offense). See you around.

Comment: I'm just here to help people, and learn things with challenging problems. What you are trying to do here is a shame. Did you watch the images of the question? No, because you would not be writing such nonsense. `.filter(app => app.id !== null)` yes it is, who said it wasn't??? It is your only argument? No wonder you gave up. You are on a website that is supposed to help people, if you are here to downvote without being able to explain why, just get out, it's that simple. Nobody needs your childish and disrespectful attitude, nobody got time for that. See you around.